# Complex layout manipulation with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm playing with flexbox and trying to make some complex layout manipulation.
I want to create an easy way to do mobile-first layouts that distributes some divs to sidebars in desktop version.

Like this:

```
Mobile    Desktop
A         D  A  B
B            E
C            C
D            F
E         
F
```

After some test I've get to this solution: http://codepen.io/matheusoj/pen/MbWxoV

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 3000px;
  align-content: center;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.a {
  background-color: #fc0;
  height: 500px;
}
.b {
  background-color: #c00;
}
.c {
  background-color: #0c0;
}
.d {
  background-color: #aaf;
  height: 200px;
}
.e {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.f {
  background-color: pink;
}
.clear {
  width: 0;
  flex-basis: 0%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .left {
    order: 150;
    width: 200px;
  }
  .center {
    order: 250;
    width: 600px;
  }
  .right {
    order: 350;
    width: 200px;
  }
  .a {
    order: 201;
  }
  .e {
    order: 202;
  }
  .clear {
    width: 0;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="a center">A</div>
  <div class="b right">B</div>
  <div class="c center">C</div>
  <div class="d left">D</div>
  <div class="e center">E</div>
  <div class="f center">F</div>

  <!--  ".clear" is used to brake the columns, it should always be at the end  -->
  <div class="clear left"></div>
  <div class="clear center"></div>
</main>
```

---

The problem is that `<main>` element needs a fixed height to work. I could not make it work with a fluid height.

Can the same result be achieved without having a fixed height on the `<main>` element?

Comment: I guess u need to give a fixed height as your using flex-wrap

Answer (score 2):

You could use `absolute` position in your `.left` and `.right` flex items.

---

Remove the fixed height value you set in `<main>` and use this in your media query:

```
main {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20%; /* padding-left = .left class width */
    padding-right: 20%; /* padding-right = .right class width */
  }
  .left {
    /* order: 150; Removed. It is not needed because the element is not in the normal flow  of the document*/
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .center {
    order: 250;
    /* width: 600px; Removed */
  }
  .right {
     /* order: 350; Removed. It is not needed because the element is not in the normal flow  of the document*/
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.a {
  background-color: #fc0;
  height: 500px;
}
.b {
  background-color: #c00;
}
.c {
  background-color: #0c0;
}
.d {
  background-color: #aaf;
  height: 200px;
}
.e {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.f {
  background-color: pink;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  main {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
  }
  .left {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .center {
    order: 250;
  }
  .right {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .a {
    order: 201;
  }
  .e {
    order: 202;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="a center">A</div>
  <div class="b right">B</div>
  <div class="c center">C</div>
  <div class="d left">D</div>
  <div class="e center">E</div>
  <div class="f center">F</div>
</main>
```

---

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOyLGX)

---

Or you can do this:

```
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Changed value to center */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .left {
    order: -1;
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
  .center {
    flex-basis: 60%;

  }
  .right {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
}
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.a {
  background-color: #fc0;
  height: 500px;
}
.b {
  background-color: #c00;
}
.c {
  background-color: #0c0;
}
.d {
  background-color: #aaf;
  height: 200px;
}
.e {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.f {
  background-color: pink;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .left {
    order: -1;
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
  .center {
    flex-basis: 60%;
  }
  .right {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="a center">A</div>
  <div class="b right">B</div>
  <div class="c center">C</div>
  <div class="d left">D</div>
  <div class="e center">E</div>
  <div class="f center">F</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks. That fix my example, but doesn't work if i need to distribute more divs to sidebars.

Comment: @matheusoj So basically you want to simulate 2 aside elements and a centered container, similar to what [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) does, but using a single flex container?